# Launching application on call

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone application. I am creating a new application which should work in background and activate when call comes. I understand truecaller works in similar way.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multitasking on iPhone isn't like on the others. So you can't run your application really in background excepted you want to use music or something like this.

Also, you can't detect if the user is calling or not.

Comment: Can you please check this video and tell how truecaller works in background? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp3Gua5jks4

Comment: I just had a look... I believe it just updates your phone book.

Comment: TrueCaller runs in this video on an older iPhone without multitasking and it can't access to your calls but to your phonebook and it adds for example a number to a contact called "Blocked by TrueCaller". It uses its possibilities very well but it can't access your calls ;-)

Answer (score 0):

An application running in the background has only one way to make itself felt: send a Push Notification